# Not able to get unique records using distinct in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a subscription collection. It has around 8 million records. I want to get unique records count based on `phoneNumber`.

As mongo has `distinct query` to get unique documents from a collection.

I execute below query:

```
db.getCollection('subscriptions').distinct('phoneNumber')
```

But the above query throws cap error:

> Error: distinct too big, 16mb cap

Then I tried with aggregation as well. I used `$group` to achieve this. But because the number of records is 8 million it is not giving me the records. I wait a long but got nothing.

This is my aggregation query:

```
  subscription.aggregate([
        { $group: { _id: "$phoneNumber", subscribers: { $sum: 1 } } }
    ], function (err, docs) {
        if (docs) {
            console.log(docs);
            console.log(docs.length);
        }
    });
```

What can I do to achieve this?